# how to combine raster layers from a stack into a data frame R

Tags: r, stack, dataframe

I have a stack made of rasters

```
s<-stack(list of ASCI files)
```

I am trying to perform this operation

```
df<-as.data.frame(c(s[[1]],s[[2]],s[[2]],s[["bathymetry"]]))
```

but I get this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("RasterLayer", package = "raster")" to a data.frame
```

When I perform this operation on a single raster such as

```
df<-as.data.frame(s[[1]])
```

everything works fine. But I have to extract many rasters and combined them in one dataframe. The only solution I see now is to extract them individually and then combined them, is there a better solution? I am working with hundreds of raster at a time.

EDIT: I should also add that this function goes inside a loop and I am only extracting a subset of the raster on each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a function to each element of a list, the apply family commands are helpful:

```
lapply( s, as.data.frame )
```

That returns a list of data.frames.

To restrict it to only the elements that you want, just subset to a smaller list beforehand.

```
s_small <- s[c(1,2,3,5)]
lapply( s_small, as.data.frame )
```

Comment: thanks but I am not converting all elements at once, I am only converting elements based on a variable.

Comment: @user4050 Solution is the same--just `lapply` a list containing only the elements you want (see example above).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am still puzzled why it's not possible to use the as.data.frame in conjunction with c.

Comment: @user4050 Look at the difference between `c`, `cbind`, and `rbind`.

Comment: I am not sure this is working the way I want. I am getting this  Length Class      Mode
[1,] 3      data.frame list
[2,] 3      data.frame list
[3,] 3      data.frame list
[4,] 3      data.frame list
[5,] 3      data.frame list
but I wanted a dataframe with: y,x,raster1, raster2,etc as columns.

Comment: `lapply` returns a list.  You can try `sapply` or use `taRifx::stack`: `library(taRifx)` followed by `stack(lapply( s_small, as.data.frame ))`.  Consider posting a reproducible example next time.  You will get better answers sooner.

Answer (score 5):

Or use...

```
data.frame( rasterToPoints( s ) )
```

Drop the columns you don't want afterwards.

Comment: I am getting an error here, I am using it like this  test<-as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(s))  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"list"’

Comment: @user4050 sorry, try `data.frame` rather than `as.data.frame`

Comment: I tried but I still get what seems to be a list of data frames. I don't know this structure  Length Class  Mode   
[1,] 16806  -none- numeric
[2,] 16806  -none- numeric
[3,] 16806  -none- numeric
[4,] 16551  -none- numeric
[5,] 29400  -none- numeric
the function you suggested works if I do one layer singularly.